# User Login form issue in selecting user and password from DB

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, user-input

I have user login form ( user name and password ) in the code below I want it to check if the user and pass are exist in data base or not but when enter the user and pass it is not giving me access to form2 always I get an error login message I think there is no connection with data base or it is not reading the if condition ?

my table name is account and contains two columns (user, pass)
data base name Database1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testdb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;";


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from account where user=@username and Pass=@password", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox1.Text);

            cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cn.Close();
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            if (count == 1)
            {

                Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                this.Hide();
                form2.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login please check username and password");
            }
            cn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        }

}
```

}

this line

```
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::testdb.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
```

I changed it to

```
string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;";
```

Note: db it is existing in visual studio means I'm using the DB which comes with visual studio and I already defined the table account with the user name and pass

---

This is my issue I get error message even with correct user and password
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E72qY.png)

here my data base into VS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7quL.png)

Other snapshots can be found in my reply

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? Find place where debugger will stop and write down the message/warning/error it gives you.

Comment: You are always getting "Invalid Login please check username and password" error message ? If yes then your database connection is working fine but in case you are getting some exception message then there is issue in DB call.

Comment: Without know what your data looks like or what error you're getting, its impossible for us to help you. Please update your question to include some more details.

Comment: here the defined users, sometimes I get an error when I press refresh button


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AIO1.pnghere the error 


 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nge70.png

Answer (score 1):

At login, the system is basically asking the user to tell it 2 things:

- This is who I am (username, email address, etc.), and
- This is what I know (password)

So when you're evaluating this input from the user, you should do it the same way; that is to say by checking the *identity* (who I am) of the user first, and then comparing the password (what I know).

Consider the following example:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from account where user=@username", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox2.Text);

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            // A user with this username exists, check the password.
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] == textBox1.Text)
            {
                // The login succeeded, show Form2.
                Form2.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login please check username and password");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No user with the given username exists.
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login please check username and password");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If there are no users with the specified username, you'll get the "invalid login" error.

If the password that the user logged in with doesn't match the password in the database, you'll get the "invalid login" error.

If the system can't connect to the database, you'll get an error message from your `catch` block.

If all goes well, Form2 should be displayed when the user logs in.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code no errors I also changed this line                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] == textBox1.Text) to                         ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString() == textBox1.Text)     to convert it to string as we have object and string but nothing changed : (     see the snapshots above I updated my question there